# Permissions for a custom authorization lambda using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am implementing a backend using AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway

The lambdas are deployed using terraform

My authorization lambda does not work properly when deployed, this is the log output after firing an endpoint requiring authentication from Postman

```
(59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3) Extended Request Id: Z4N_kFTMCGYF5MA=
(59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3) Starting authorizer: 5h083y for request: 59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3
(59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3) Incoming identity: ************************************************************************************************************************************************************lAxM0k
(59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3) Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
(59ce7d79-2f24-4255-b24b-8ac02c8f33c3) Execution failed due to configuration error: Authorizer error
```

Testing the lambda locally and in the AWS console provides me correct outputs, so it is not a function issue, but rather a permission issue

Here is the output from the lambda when tested:

```
{
  "principalId": "******",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "pid": "******"
  }
}
```

After verifying my terraform files, the authorizer lambda does not have any `resource "aws_lambda_permission"` declaration, but so is another authorizer lambda from a similar project, which works properly

I have added this locally, and using `terraform plan` does not seem to show any error

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambdaApiAuthorizerPermission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambdaApiAuthorizer.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Relevant configurations from other terraform files

Here is from the api.tf file:

```
// Authorizer
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "ApiAuthorizer" {
  name                              = "authorizer-jwt"
  rest_api_id                       = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  authorizer_uri                    = aws_lambda_function.lambdaApiAuthorizer.invoke_arn
  authorizer_credentials            = data.aws_iam_role.terraform-commande.arn
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = var.api_authorizer_jwt_ttl
}
```

Here is the authorizer function declaration

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambdaApiAuthorizer" {
  function_name = "${var.app}-${var.env}-${local.lambdaApiAuthorizerName}"
  description   = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerDescription
  layers = [
    data.aws_lambda_layer_version.LambdaLayerDependenciesDefault.arn
  ]
  handler = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerHandler
  role    = data.aws_iam_role.terraform-commande.arn

  filename         = data.archive_file.lambdaApiAuthorizer.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambdaApiAuthorizer.output_base64sha256

  runtime     = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerRuntime
  timeout     = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerTimeout
  memory_size = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerMemory

  environment {
    variables = local.lambdaApiAuthorizerEnvironments
  }

  //part of vpc to be able to access database
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [data.aws_subnet.vpc_subnet_pri_commande_a.id, data.aws_subnet.vpc_subnet_pri_commande_b.id]
    security_group_ids = [data.aws_security_group.bastion.id]
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = var.app
    Environment = var.env
    MANAGED_BY  = "terraform"
  }
}
```

And here is the configuration of the authorizer in other terraform files to use that lambda as an authorizer

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "lambdaApiGetClients" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  resource_id   = local.lambdaApiGetClientsRouteParent
  http_method   = local.lambdaApiGetClientsMethod
  api_key_required = false
  authorization = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.ApiAuthorizer.id
}
```

Note: I have non-api lambdas (SQS) who do not have any permission declaration either

<s>Will deploying this block allow the lambda to be executed? Or am I missing some properties?</s>

Update: I have applied the permission command block in the question and the error is still there

I may have to explain what the authorizer lambda does:

- It receives a JWT token from an event
- It decodes the token
- It looks for the corresponding user in the database
- If it finds the user in the database, it generates an Allow policy and returns it
- It if does not find the user in the database, it generates a Deny policy and returns it
- The user pid can then be used in other lambdas from the returned context as en event property

And for more clarification:

- I have an endpoint that does not require any authentication, I can call it no problem from Postman
- My login endpoint returns a correct authentication token, that I use as authentication of other endpoints from Postman
- But when I call the endpoints using said token, it provokes an error 500 with the following output:

```json
{
  "message": null
}
```

Is there any permission configuration that I may be missing here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `Testing the lambda locally and in the AWS console provides me correct outputs`?

Comment: @MarkoE the outputs that I was waiting for, an Allow/Deny policy from the authorization lambda

Comment: Ok, but what does testing the lambda locally mean?

Comment: @MarkoE oh, using the nodejs module `lambda-local` like this: `lambda-local -t 900000 src/index.js -h handler -e env/event.js --envfile env/dev.env`

Comment: So you have set the AWS credentials required by this package?

Comment: I have not, but I have been given the access keys

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you conclude it was working then if you weren't hitting the same API Gateway endpoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248751/discussion-between-prout-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were missing `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` in our `resource "aws_iam_role_policy"` declaration

Now it works like a charm

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "myrole" {
  name = default
  role = aws_iam_role.myrole.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        ...
      ],
      "Resource": [...]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: You my friend is the hero we all need, but don't deserve! :)